# Android: display bugs when rotating device 90°

Tags: android, rotation

I built an android game, with various buttons and textViews, which works satisfactorily. However when I rotate the device (phone or tablet) 90 degrees, strange bugs appear.

For possible answers, I've looked at those questions:
1) Background task, progress dialog, orientation change - is there any 100% working solution?
2) Rotation of screen crashes android app [duplicate]

Yet they don't answer my problem, because I don't use elaborate async background task, and my app doesn't crash.

When I turn the device, it empties some textViews, fills some other, but some arrays of values, where I keep track of things, stay correct... ???

Question 1: is there a simple way to have the device change nothing when turned? (android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in manifest doesn't do the trick for me)

Question 2: how come Google/Android accepts such behavior?

Comment: try to save current state of activity   http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/03/save-and-restore-instance-state.html  or http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Saving_and_Restoring_the_User_Interface_State_of_an_Android_Activity

Comment: Finally, I solved my problem by detecting an orientation angle substantial change, and redisplaying data that were kept correct.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understand. One has to take into account the evolution of the activiy through its life cycle. When rotating the device, the activity goes successively through:

```
onPause 
onSaveInstanceState 
onStop 
onDestroy 
onCreate 
onStart 
onRestoreInstanceState 
onResume
```

In the process, some aspects (information) of the activity are preserved and restored on resume, and some are not. The data I wanted to preserve were not. But I built a way to recreate them. For more, as koutuk suggests, see Neil Smyth's book "Android Studio Developments", also available for free on techotopia.com, chapter 13.